# AWS KMS Convert Public Key PEM file as Cer file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I am trying to reuse the public key from customer managed keys in AWS Key Management Service for encryption outside of AWS. When I download the key from AWS, it is stored as a pem file. I need to be able to convert to a cer file that will be used to import to Windows Certificate Store. However, when I change the file extension to cer and try to open it, I get the following error: The file is invalid for use as a security certificate. How can I convert this pem file to an useable cer file?

Per their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/download-public-key.html#download-public-key-considerations), it has the following step when downloading the file, so I am wondering if its missing important information in the pem file to convert to a cer file:

Choose the Cryptographic configuration tab. Record the values of the Key spec, Key usage, and Encryption algorithms or Signing Algorithms fields. You'll need to use these values to use the public key outside of AWS KMS. Be sure to share this information when you share the public key.